# What can I do to work on uneven shoulders / back?

Tags: shoulders, dumbbells, back, barbell

During a bench press, on the way down, my spotters tell me that my barbell is coming down a bit slanted, which I think means that I have uneven shoulders / back.

What can I do instead to correct this?

I am thinking switching over to dumbbell chest presses as well as shoulder presses -- and avoid the barbell altogether.

Should I see a chiropractor?  I rather not spend money if I don't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing you’ve said suggests that you have uneven shoulder or back muscles.

While I’m a fan of dumbbells, I don’t see that as a solution because it has the potential to exasperate the problem by allowing your arms to move even more freely. What you need to work on is your form. Find a mirror to practice and exercise in front of and watch yourself. Record yourself, take notes at how it feels, and continually work with the feedback you get from these sources.